# Could a funny CAPTCHA be more pleasant?

Tags: website-design, captcha

I think one way to make CAPTCHA be more acceptable is to make it funny, but for some reason most CAPTCHA do not do this. Would this be seen as unprofessional or could this be a good way to make a necessary annoyance more engaging and amusing?

Comment: But Captcha are funny http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/inglip

Comment: The CAPTCHA here in StackExchange sites is funny...

Comment: @MattRockwell I can't quite tell if you're a human. Please fill out this form...:)

Comment: @Matt Rockwell good to know, thx for that! could you explain in details all the jokes? it would be very useful for normal people (not from US or whatever you guys are)

Comment: The basic humor I've seen on Captcha pages is to poke fun at the user saying we don't know if you're a robot, which is what SE does. I don't know if anyone has a screenshot of it though.

Comment: @Ben Brocka I remember, its very funny after you see it like 100 times. it grows on you. SO is very funny, please don't forget it.

Answer (score 8):

The CAPTCHA used on the UX.SE(and most likely other SE sites) is brilliant. It is light hearted and gives a chuckle instead of annoying you. This might not appease **everyone**, but it sure attempts to make light of an annoying situation. Also while being funny, it gives context to **why** you are being asked to enter the CAPTCHA text, to prove "I'm a Human Being".

[image]

It also goes on to explain on the right side:

> Are you a human being? We apologize for the confusion, but we can't *quite* tell if you're a person or a script. Please don't take this personally. Bot and scripts can be remarkably lifelike these days! Enter the CAPTCHA displayed, and we'll be out of your way.

Comment: it was funny in the beginning of SO, its just boring.

Comment: @0101 It seems you are hard to please :)

Comment: You missed the copy at the side! That's the best part http://i.stack.imgur.com/9m7uI.png

Comment: @BenBrocka Added it to my answer, thanks for that!

Comment: The human verification above is great!!!! I like it!

Comment: @MattRockwell same thing for 3 years is still funny to you ?

Comment: @0101 Considering see it once a week at a maximum yes. I haven't seen it in weeks now. I'm not sure why you are running into this as often as you seem to be...

Comment: @MattRockwell I'm too fast and not from us. isn't that reason enough ? maybe color of my skin is also unsupported.

Comment: @0101 I wouldn't think any of that would be true. The only thing I can think of is that you are repeatedly posting questions/answers back to back, but do you really do that often?

Answer (score 1):

I think Captchas should be simple. The user has no interest to decode cryptic pictures. But I don't know how secure are some simpler captchas...

Examples for simpler Captchas:
http://serie3.info/s3capcha/demonstration.php

http://uxmovement.com/forms/captchas-vs-spambots-why-the-checkbox-captcha-wins/

Comment: what should be and what it is is not the same ;) look at SO, it should be praecursor, but its worst than facebook.